# Advice wanted: Docker Infastructure for the newbie, Flynn, Dokku and Deis or just plain docker?

Tags: deployment, docker, ruby-on-rails, ruby

To give some background we are a development Agency, mostly using Ruby/Rails to develop complex data driven web applications.
These applications usually make use of various services such as a database, caching layer, full text indexing, etc...

We have started to use docker locally for development and want to start deploying with it.

We currently use Puppet, Continues Deployment and all the usual kool aid...

We are looking at rolling out Flynn, Docker or Deis and currently thinking Flynn but I'm wondering if we should bother at all?
Is there a simpler or native docker solution (like swarm) that we are missing?

What we want is the ability to quickly launch applications, if its heroku like than that's a bonus for us but really we are competent enough to be able to manage something that doesn't have all the bells and whistles in favour of something that's easier to manage and roll out long term.

We'll have to repeat this setup over and over and be able to manage it for multiple customers so it needs to be well understood and reliable.
We like simplicity!

So what route would you recommend us to go down?

Thanks very much in advance.

Paul

Comment: You've just described [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.org/).

Comment: Thanks very much Michael, I'll take a look at OpenShift.